# Trouble Deleting a node in Red-Black-Tree (C code)

Tags: c, red-black-tree

I'm trying to build a Red-Black Tree skeleton, according
to cormen algorithms.

So far Insert, Search and InsertFixup and any related methods (like Left\Right Rotate) are all working properly.

My problem is with deleting a node - The tree doesn't fix properly.

I'm comparing my tree after deleting a
node to the tree in the following RB-TREE-simulator:
https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/RedBlack.html

The algorithms i'm using:
RB-DELETE

```
/*
RB-DELETE(T, z)
1 if left[z] = nil[T] or right[z] = nil[T]
2    then y ← z
3    else y ← TREE-SUCCESSOR(z)
4 if left[y] ≠ nil[T]
5    then x ← left[y]
6    else x ← right[y]
7 p[x] ← p[y]
8 if p[y] = nil[T]
9    then root[T] ← x
10    else if y = left[p[y]]
11            then left[p[y]] ← x
12            else right[p[y]] ← x
13 if y != z
14    then key[z] ← key[y]
15         copy y's satellite data into z
16 if color[y] = BLACK
17    then RB-DELETE-FIXUP(T, x)
18 return y
```

DELETE-FIXUP

```
 RB-DELETE-FIXUP(T, x)
 1 while x ≠ root[T] and color[x] = BLACK
 2     do if x = left[p[x]]
 3           then w ← right[p[x]]
 4                if color[w] = RED
 5                   then color[w] ← BLACK                        ▹  Case 1
 6                        color[p[x]] ← RED                       ▹  Case 1
 7                        LEFT-ROTATE(T, p[x])                    ▹  Case 1
 8                        w ← right[p[x]]                         ▹  Case 1
 9                if color[left[w]] = BLACK and color[right[w]] = BLACK
 10                   then color[w] ← RED                          ▹  Case 2
 11                        x p[x]                                  ▹  Case 2
 12                   else if color[right[w]] = BLACK
 13                           then color[left[w]] ← BLACK          ▹  Case 3
 14                                color[w] ← RED                  ▹  Case 3
 15                                RIGHT-ROTATE(T, w)              ▹  Case 3
 16                                w ← right[p[x]]                 ▹  Case 3
 17                         color[w] ← color[p[x]]                 ▹  Case 4
 18                         color[p[x]] ← BLACK                    ▹  Case 4
 19                         color[right[w]] ← BLACK                ▹  Case 4
 20                         LEFT-ROTATE(T, p[x])                   ▹  Case 4
 21                         x ← root[T]                            ▹  Case 4
 22        else (same as then clause with "right" and "left" exchanged)
 23 color[x] ← BLACK
```

And My actual code:

**1. Transplant**

```
static void RBTreeTransplant(RBtree_node_t ** pRoot,
    RBtree_node_t * pDeletedNode, RBtree_node_t * pBrother) {
if (NULL == pDeletedNode->parent) {
    *pRoot = pBrother;
} else if (pDeletedNode == pDeletedNode->parent->left) {
    pDeletedNode->parent->left = pBrother;
} else {
    pDeletedNode->parent->right = pBrother;
}

pBrother->parent = pDeletedNode->parent;
} // RBTreeTransplant
```

**2. DeletFixUp**

```
static void RBDeleteFixUp(RBtree_node_t ** pRoot, RBtree_node_t * pNode) {
RBtree_node_t * pAidNode = NULL;

while ((pNode != *pRoot) && (pNode->color == RB_COLOR_BLACK)) {
    if (pNode == pNode->parent->left) {
        pAidNode = pNode->parent->right; // pAidNode is pNode's brother

        // CASE1: pNode's brother is RED:
        // * Paint pNode's brother(pAidNode) BLACK
        // * Paint pNode's parent RED
        // * Left Rotate pNode's parent
        // * point pAidNode to pNode's Parent right children
        if (pAidNode->color == RB_COLOR_RED) {
            pAidNode->color = RB_COLOR_BLACK;
            pNode->parent->color = RB_COLOR_RED;
            RBRotate(pRoot, pNode->parent, RB_ROTATE_LEFT);
            pAidNode = pNode->parent->right;
            continue;
        } // CASE1

        // CASE2: pNode's brother is BLACK and both his childrens are BLACK
        // * Paint pNode's brother(pAideNode) RED
        // * point pNode to pNode's parent
        if ((pAidNode->left->color == RB_COLOR_BLACK)
                && (pAidNode->right->color == RB_COLOR_BLACK)) {
            pAidNode = RB_COLOR_RED;
            pNode = pNode->parent;
            continue;
        } // CASE2

        //CASE3: pNode's brother and his brother right children is BLACK
        // * Paint pAidNode LEFT children as BLACK
        // * Paint pAidNode as RED
        // * Right Rotate pAidNode
        // * point pAidNode to pNode parent right children
        else if (pAidNode->right->color == RB_COLOR_BLACK) {
            pAidNode->left->color = RB_COLOR_BLACK;
            pAidNode->color = RB_COLOR_RED;
            RBRotate(pRoot, pAidNode, RB_ROTATE_RIGHT);
            pAidNode = pNode->parent->right;
            continue;
        } // CASE3

        //CASE4: pNode's brother is BLACK, and his brother right children is RED
        // * Paint pAidNode as pNode's parent
        // * Paint pNode's parent BLACK
        // * Paint pAidNode right children BLACK
        // * Left Rotate pNode's parent
        // * Set pNode as the new root
        pAidNode->color = pNode->parent->color;
        pNode->parent->color = RB_COLOR_BLACK;
        pAidNode->right->color = RB_COLOR_BLACK;
        RBRotate(pRoot, pNode->parent, RB_ROTATE_LEFT);
        pNode = *pRoot;
    }
} // while

pNode->color = RB_COLOR_BLACK;
 } // RBTreeDeleteFixUp
```

**3. NodeDelete**

```
static StatusType RBNodeDelete(RBtree_node_t ** pRoot,
    RBtree_node_t * pNode) {
RBtree_node_t * pAidNode = pNode;
RBtree_node_t * pExtraAidNode = NULL;
RBtree_color originalNodeColor = RB_COLOR_BLACK;

if ((NULL == pRoot) || (NULL == *pRoot) || (NULL == pNode)) {
    return INVALID_INPUT;
}

originalNodeColor = pNode->color;

// CASE1: Node to delete has no LEFT.
if (NULL == pNode->left) {
    pExtraAidNode = pNode->right;
    RBTreeTransplant(pRoot, pNode, pNode->right);
} // End of CASE1

// CASE2: Node to delete has LEFT but has no RIGHT
else if (NULL == pNode->right) {
    pExtraAidNode = pNode->left;
    RBTreeTransplant(pRoot, pNode, pNode->left);
} // End of CASE2

// CASE3: Node to delete has both children
else {
    pAidNode = RBTreeMin(pNode->right); // Find Successor
    originalNodeColor = pAidNode->color; // Save color of successor
    pExtraAidNode = pAidNode->right;

    if (pAidNode->parent == pNode) { // Successor has no LEFT cause its nill
        pExtraAidNode->parent = pAidNode;
    } else {
        RBTreeTransplant(pRoot, pAidNode, pAidNode->right);
        pAidNode->right = pNode->right;
        pAidNode->right->parent = pAidNode;
    }

    RBTreeTransplant(pRoot, pNode, pAidNode);
    pAidNode->left = pNode->left;
    pAidNode->left->parent = pAidNode;
    pAidNode->color = pNode->color;
} // End of CASE3

if (originalNodeColor == RB_COLOR_BLACK) {
    RBDeleteFixUp(pRoot, pExtraAidNode);
}

// Free allocated node memory
RBTreeSingleNodeDestroy(pNode);

return SUCCESS;
```

I'll be glad to know what am i doing wrong in my delete\deletefixup
that messing the delete implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised your `DeleteFixUp` works. In case 2 you have `pAidNode = RB_COLOR_RED;` but you should assign to the node's color, not the node itself. You're also missing the highest-level `else` case inside the while loop which corresponds to this part in the pseudo-code: `else (same as then clause with "right" and "left" exchanged)`. Did you post the correct code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i'm adding an answer to thread the correct way.

Seems like my whole problem was not the code,

but the RBTREE Simulator link i've compared with.

Not sure what's really going on in that site, 
but after almost giving up and manually checking the received tree after
deleting of nodes from it -

it seems that after each delete i get a perfectly balanced Red Black Tree,
with all of features implemented.

Sorry for wasting any of your time.

Good Night

Answer (score 0):

Depending on a sequence of insertions and deletions, we can produce two RB-trees containing the same keys but having different shapes.
Of course, given such a sequence, the final tree must always be the same. The simulator is useful in that sense (although in your case it appears to be broken?!).

Anyhow, it may be useful to have a function that checks if a given tree actually is a RB-Tree.

If you want to test the correctness of an RB-tree, you could give this a go:

```c
/**
 * This functions returns:
 *   - -1 if the tree is not valid
 *   - The number of black nodes in a path from the root to a leaf otherwise
 */
int isRBTreeValid(RBTree_node_t *root) {
    int isBlack = 1, leftBlackNodes, rightBlackNodes;
    // A leaf is black, leaves are NULL nodes.
    if (!root)
        return 1;
    // The children of a red node are black
    if (RB_COLOR_RED == root->color) {
        if ((root->left && RB_COLOR_RED == root->left->color) ||
            (root->right && RB_COLOR_RED == root->right->color)) {
            return -1;
        }
        isBlack = 0;
    }
    if (0 > (leftBlackNodes = isRBTreeValid(root->left)))
        return -1;
    if (0 > (rightBlackNodes = isRBTreeValid(root->right)))
        return -1;
    // There must be the same number of black nodes in each path from the root to a leaf.
    if (leftBlackNodes != rightBlackNodes)
        return -1;
    return isBlack + leftBlackNodes;
}
```

To complete the check, you  have to make sure the root is black. You could wrap this up into:

```c
int isRBTreeReallyValid(RBTree_node_t *root) {
    return (!root) ||
        (RB_COLOR_BLACK == root->color && 0 < isRBTreeValid(root));
}
```

Comment: Hey,
thank you for the code!

after the bad exprience of wasting hours thinking my delete function was
incorrect, i've also built my own method that does exactly what your program does.

Appreciate your effort though, sorry
and thanks :-)